# Encryption settings for Widevine CENC on Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, widevine

I want to use Azure Media Services to provide the licenses for content protection. I created the ContentKey using the PHP SDK, and got the license URL for Widevine. I'm using [packager](https://github.com/google/edash-packager) in my side to encrypt the video.

My problem is (mostly because of ignorance) that I don't know where to find the value for the parameters "--signer", "--aes_signing_key" and "--aes_signing_iv". I read in some tutorials that these values are provided by Widevine, but in my case I assumed that were provided by Azure.

It's not an issue with PHP or `packager`. Even using the REST API I don't know which information correlates to "signer" "signing key" and "signing iv". This information is required even by other platforms like [bitcodin](http://bitcodin.com) and other packagers.

Comment: Here is a PHP sample at github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/tree/master/examples/MediaServices, which applies DRM (PlayReady + Widevine) content protection.

Comment: Thank you Gary. But that's not what I'm looking for, because that example encrypts the video using Azure (which not requires the values I'm asking for) and I want to encrypt it in my own server. I want to use Azure only as a license provider.

Comment: Where should I ask to get a response from Azure? I was going to pay for support but the minimum is 6 months, and I just need to know this, I don't need 6 months of support. Is there someone I can pay to answer this question?

Comment: @StefanoVettorazzi, Would you like to use Azure AES to encrypts to protect your content? As far as I known, Azure Media Player currently supports AES-128 bit envelope encrypted content and common encrypted content (through PlayReady or Widevine). And these parameters like '"--aes_signing_key" and "--aes_signing_iv' is for AES encrypted content. And I recommend you can check these methods whether met your requirement (http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/samples.html)

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT thanks for your answer.
No, I want to use common encryption. If you want, you can check here https://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/ and here https://github.com/google/edash-packager where is mention the procedure to encrypt using Widevine. The values I mentioned are required.

Comment: @StefanoVettorazzi， Although it seems that this issue is more related to Widevine using Java, I  had involved someone familiar to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay.  Appreciate for your patience.

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT thank you. I really appreciate it. I don't have problem to wait as long as necessary.

Comment: Hi @StefanoVettorazzi, did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same thing now... I even don't know where to get the value for the parameter `content_id` (required by shaka-packager). I'm also using php by the way.

Comment: Hi @Augusto. Sorry, it's been a while since I was playing around with Wdevine and from what I remember I wasn't able to use the Azure service. The answer I got from the email contact was something about not using Widevine, which wasn't what I wanted to do. Maybe there is another service now that works "out of the box"? Also, I think it was easier for video, I don't remember why. I hope it helps. Best.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your own packager, you only need to configure the common encryption key and Widevine License template with us, you will obtain a license URL and KEY ID as return, and you can put those value into your packager.

You don't need to configure AES envelope Key, which is for AES 128 clear key encryption. That's another service that we offer.

Feel free to reach out to me at yanmf@microsoft.com if you have more questions. I am the PM on this Widevine services on Azure. We will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mingfei. I'm going to write to the email address you provided, because I still don't understand. For the packager I need the signer and a RSA private key or the signer and an AES IV plus an AES key.

Comment: Please do. I will wait for your email.

Comment: @MingfeiYan could you give syntax for shakapackager?